# How would I write a test case in Java to test that the input is an int?

Tags: java, testcase

Would I do something like this?

```
Assert.assertTrue(value = int n);
```

Also, if I had a method such as:

```
public int get(){
   return count;
}
```

What kind of a test case would I write for it? Would I write a test case testing if the return is an integer?

Comment: If the return type is an `int`, then it will always return an `int`, or else hell will freeze.

Comment: http://blog.wilshipley.com/2005/09/unit-testing-is-teh-suck-urr.html

Comment: Upvoted since this is seems like a valid question for public methods in SDKs that third parties use.. You don't want people to change input and return types without failing test cases e.g. changing from int to Integer.

Answer (score 2):

Regrading your first question - the return type is an int (so you don't need to verify that).
Regarding your second question, if it's just a getter, there's no need to write test for it.
Generally, unit test helps you to test bussiness logic and that a certain behavior of a building block of your app works.
If we'll take the count for example, you would probably want to build up a test case with actions that affects the count in a specific way and then assert on it's expected value. 
You can look [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html) for a nice tutorial on Unit Tests in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Class for testing purpose:

```
public class Item {

   private int number;

   public Item(int number) {
       this.number = number;
   }

   public int getNumber() {
       return number;
   }
}
```

Your test cases could be:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
public class Test {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testCase1() {
        Item item = new Item(1);
        assertEquals(1, item.getNumber());
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testCase2() {
        Item item = new Item(2);
        assertEquals(2, item.getNumber());
    }
}
```

You can verify your business logic via assertEquals method.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I write a test case in Java to test that the input is an int?

Assuming your concern is someone could change input type of a method.

```
public final void testSet() {
    try {
        MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("set", new Class[] { Integer.TYPE });
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        Assert.assertFalse(true);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> Would I write a test case testing if the return is an integer?

Assuming your concern is someone could change return type of a method. By the way you are returning *int* in your example so I have used Integer.**TYPE**, if you want to check for *Integer* then use Integer.**class**

```
public final void testGet() {
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Method m = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("get", null);
        Assert.assertTrue(m.getReturnType() == Integer.TYPE);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```